# How to Change a Visibility Window property from the one form to another?

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, window, visibility

In my current project. I click a button and the main form will set the ShowIcon false and the Visibility to false. Once I terminate the second window, I want to see the main form again. By resetting both properties to true. How is that possible?

As well where would I place the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in your `button_click` event:

```
newform nf = new newform(); //or whatever the name of your second form is
this.Hide(); //to hide your mainform
nf.ShowDialog();
this.Show(); //to show your mainform after closing your new form
nf.Dispose(); //optional
```

Answer (score 0):

You can overRide the `OnFormClossing` event

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
     // code that u want
}
```

Comment: Question. Where would I put this and how would both forms communicate with each other?

Comment: Did you try to use form2.ShowDialog(); May be this is what u required